# ModalPopupExtender is not triggered in ASP.NET gridview image button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to display AJAX popup with confirmation message for the user, but when the user is clicking the button automatically goes to the button click event without displaying the message.
This is what I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton1" RowIndex='<%# Eval("PostingID") %>' CommandName="Archive" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostingID") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/a.png" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirm" runat="server" CssClass="modalPanel" Style="display: none; height:160px; border-color:#B6B6B4;">
               <div>
                  <table class="featrEmpDivLoginPopup" style="height:160px; width:460px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td id="divClose" runat="server" class="topimglhs533 hedding1" style="height:30px; background-color:#d3d8d2;">
                           Message 
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <div id="jsAlert1_popupBody" style="position: absolute; font-family: Verdana,Arial; font-size: 9pt; padding: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black; top: 34px; width: 450px; left: 1px;">
                              <div style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">Are you sure you want to Archive this posting?<br></div>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center;">
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Archive" ImageUrl="~/Images/btnarchive.jpg" runat="server" />
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel2.jpg" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgButton1" PopupControlID="pnlConfirm"
               CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBg" DropShadow="false"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <!-- PANEL -->
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So I'm expecting the popup to be shown when the user will click on imgButton1 but instead it goes to the event right away in the code behind.

Is there anything wrong in this code?

### Explanation added

In Firebug, I'm able to see these two errors in ScriptResource.axd:

[image]

Can that be related to the problem I have?

Better picture added:

[image]

Comment: Does adding `OnClientCLick="return false;` to the `ImageButton (imgButton1)' help?

Comment: @DennisR no postback happens but also the popup is not shown as well. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some cs code for your imagebutton click event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't had UpdatePanel with ContentTemplate for the page. Once I did put them in place the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think following "imgButton1" in side the grid so there is no way to get "imgButton1" in to ModalPopupExtender.

You can do the following steps if you prefer to do 
1. Add ModalPopupExtender with fake Target controls

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkEditPopup" TargetControlID="hfo" DropShadow="true"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pAddEditApprover" runat="server">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<%-- START : Fake Controler for ModalPopupExtender --%>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfo" runat="server" />
<%-- END : Fake Controler for ModalPopupExtender --%>
```

2. Use Item command in grid view

   ```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"OnSelectedIndexChanging="gv_SelectedIndexChanging">
       <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField 
   SelectImageUrl="~/Styles/images/info-group.png" 
   ButtonType="Image" 
   ShowSelectButton="true"  
   AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" /> ... // rest of grid data
   ```

3 in .cs file

```
 protected void gridApprover_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {
  lnkEditPopup.Show();
  }
```

Try this one it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is when you click the image button event is not fire so to solve this problem that I think you should call to popup extender from the image button event.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    TargetControlID="FakeHiddenField" PopupControlID="Panel4" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
    Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Then go to image button event (method) in the .cs and write this code there

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```

try this this, it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a Confirmation if he wants to archive this posting, why don't you use JavaScript?

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;"
```

This makes a JavaScript alert with the opportunity to check what the user wants.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton1" RowIndex='<%# Eval("PostingID") %>' OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" CommandName="Archive" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostingID") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/a.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the issue is that `imgButton1`, `pnlConfirm` and `ModalPopupExtender1` live inside a row in your `GridView`. A `GridView` takes into account that it will have multiple rows. This means that you cannot directly reference the controls by their respective ID's.

Here's something you could do alternatively:

- Create a control that inherits from `DataControlField` - to be able to add it to your rows..
- Create an `ImageButton` inside of the control.
- Add a message to the `OnClientClick` event for the imagebutton.
- Use your new control in any GridView`.

Some example code here:

```
public class GridDeleteButton : DataControlField, IDisposable
{
    private ImageButton button;
    public event ImageClickEventHandler Click;

    public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
    {
        button = new ImageButton
                 {
                     ImageUrl = "...",
                     CommandName = "Delete",
                     OnClientClick = @"return confirm('Are you sure?');"
                 };

        if (Click != null) button.Click += Click;

        cell.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    protected override DataControlField CreateField()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (button != null) button.Dispose();
    }
}
```